# Merge two while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have two while loops that take up a lot of space on my code. I was wondering if anyone knew how to merge them to make my code neater and smaller as I don't even know where to start. I've looked around and can't find how to merge two almost identical loops. Hope someone helps me. I found a question very similar to this but to me the answer doesn't make sense to me as the code doesn't work and I tried to fix it. Here is the code.

```
for i in range(5):
while True:
    print(" ")
    input("Press enter to roll player 1 ")
    print("Rolling dice!")
    roll1=random.randint(1,6)
    roll2=random.randint(1,6)
    print(roll1)
    print(roll2)
    total=(roll1 + roll2)
    print("Your total is:" ,total)
    score1=score1 +total

    if roll1 is roll2:
        if total in even:
            score1=score1 +10
            print(score1)
            print("You rolled a double. Roll again.")
            continue
        elif total in odd:
            score1-score1 -5
            print(score1)
            print("You rolled a double. Roll again.")
            continue

    elif total in even:
        score1=score1 +10
        print(score1)
        break

    elif total in odd:
        score1=score1 -5
        print(score1)
        break

if score1<0:
    print("Player 1, you went under 0. Game over.")
    break

while True:
    print(" ")
    input("Press enter to roll player 2 ")
    print("Rolling dice!")
    roll1=random.randint(1,6)
    roll2=random.randint(1,6)
    print(roll1)
    print(roll2)
    total=(roll1 + roll2)
    print("Your total is:" ,total)
    score2=score2 +total

    if roll1 is roll2:
        if total in even:
            score2=score2 +10
            print(score2)
            print("You rolled a double. Roll again.")
            continue
        elif total in odd:
            score2=score2 -5
            print(score2)
            print("You rolled a double. Roll again.")
            continue

    elif total in even:
        score2=score2 +10
        print(score2)
        break

    elif total in odd:
        score2=score2 -5
        print(score2)
        break

if score2<0:
    print("Player 2, you went under 0. Game over.")
    break
```

As you can see they are practically identical apart from the player 1 going to player 2 and score 1 goes to score 2. How can I simplify this code?

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Questions like "please tell me how to improve this" or generally asking to write code for you are not well-regarded around here. You are more likely to receive a polite and well-grounded answer if you ask a concise question regarding errors or uncertainties. That said, I would recommend you look into object-oriented programming in Python and implement a class `Player` with a `run()` method encapsulating your logic. That way, it'll scale to 7 million players easily :)

Comment: The two loops are 99.9% identical. Just make them a function taking the name of the player as a parameter (and returning the score, if that's needed at all, but it seems like it's not) and call that function two times, once for player 1 and once for player 2.

Comment: Just because you are looking for a solution and this is a hard thing to look up, I'm going to suggest to you to go and read about "functions". They are fundamental building blocks of virtually any language and the number one tool for code reuse.

Comment: i'll keep that in mind and thanks for the answer.

Comment: In addition to Oliver's advices, when posting your python code double check the identation because it could be source of sintax errors.

Comment: Also, you never initialize `score1` and `score1-score1 -5` should be `score1=score1 -5`

Comment: Have you tried replacing the non-identical parts with variables? You could use `player = 0` and `player = 1` and use `scores = [0, 0]` to replace the `score1` and `score2` variables with `score[player]`..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a definition for that loop

```
def roller(player_num):
    while True:
        print(" ")
        input("Press enter to roll player %s " % str(player_num))
        print("Rolling dice!")
        roll1=random.randint(1,6)
        roll2=random.randint(1,6)
        print(roll1)
        print(roll2)
        total=(roll1 + roll2)
        print("Your total is:" ,total)
        score1=score1 +total

        if roll1 is roll2:
            if total in even:
                score1=score1 +10
                print(score1)
                print("You rolled a double. Roll again.")
                continue
            elif total in odd:
                score1-score1 -5
                print(score1)
                print("You rolled a double. Roll again.")
                continue

        elif total in even:
            score1=score1 +10
            print(score1)
            break

        elif total in odd:
            score1=score1 -5
            print(score1)
            break

    if score1<0:
        print("Player %s, you went under 0. Game over." %s str(player_num)
        break

roller(1)
roller(2)
```

Im not sure why you have break statements as that will break the loop in the first go, but here you have your code in definition and it being used for each user

Comment: Thanks this worked. The break statement was for if the score was below 0 so if it was above 0 it wouldn't break

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to avoid duplication of the same code is define a function that takes in the number of the player and modifies that player's score accordingly, like `updateScore()` or `changeScore()`. The arguments would be the number of the players (1 or 2) and how many points you'd like to change it by.

Answer (score 0):

That large `while` loop is virtually the same for Player 1 and Player 2, so you should make it a function and pass the name (or number) of the player as a parameter.

But there's more: Even within the function, there is a lot of redundancy. For instance, you check whether the roll is even in both the pair and the non-pair case, and you could further condense that part using a ternary `... if ... else ...` expression. Also, note that there are a few more problems in your code, e.g. you never seem to initialize `score1` and `score2`, and you have a typo in `score1-score1 -5`. Also, what is `even`, a list of all the even numbers? Instead, you can use `total % 2 == 0` to check whether `total` is even.

Also, your `if score < 0:` check is outside of the loop. If that's intended, the `break` does not make sense, as it would only break out of the outer `for` loop, which is probably not intended. Also, you might add some output for the case that the score is not `< 0`.

Putting all this together, the function could look something like this:

```
def roll(player):
    score = 0
    while True:
        input("\nPress enter to roll, %s" % player)
        roll1 = random.randint(1,6)
        roll2 = random.randint(1,6)
        print("Rolling dice!", roll1, roll2)
        total = roll1 + roll2
        score += total
        score += 10 if total % 2 == 0 else -5
        print("Your total is:", score)
        if roll1 == roll2:
            print("You rolled a double. Roll again.")
        else:
            break
    if score < 0:
        print("%s, you went under 0. Game over." % player)
    else:
        print("%s, your final score is %d." % (player, score))
```

Now, just call that function twice:

```
for _ in range(5):
    roll("Player 1")
    roll("Player 2")
```